# Jira api как получить данные по проекту и его пользователем

Tags: spring, api, spring-boot, rest, jira-api

Создаю приложение с помощью Spring и Angular.
И никак не могу понять как сделать запрос с помощью JIRA API чтобы получить данные пользователей конкретных проектов за прошедшую неделю.

Т.е у меня есть метод который просто по таймеру отрабатывает каждую субботу. По моей задумке он должен отработав запросить данные всех людей которые прикреплены к проекту в jira взять данные по их задачам за прошедшую неделю(имя задачи, описание, время, статус) и вернуть их в строке. Но пока не могу понять как именно сформировать такой запрос.
Помогите кто может, пожалуйста, а то уже несколько дней сижу с этим.

Ток такой варик нашел

```
GET /rest/api/2/user/search?query
```

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/How-to-get-users-assigned-to-Jira-Project-and-their/qaq-p/2219936#M238087

Comment: да, там идет запрос на список пользователеq и ролей в проекте. Но как запросить пользователей их задачи на проекте и все это в промежутке одной недели?

Там должно быть несколько каких-то запросов или можно как то одним это получить?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал использовать гугл на английском языке. Попробуйте поискать по такому запросу- "users  tasks  project week jira api"